# Undefined reference to rand() even thought it's included and defined

Tags: c, header-files, scheduler

I'm working on the **scheduler for a custom OS** we are using in class, but when I try to call the rand() function, it gives me this error:

```
In function `gen_rand_number':
sched.c:(.text+0x5e): undefined reference to `rand'
```

Here is my sched.c file

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <signal.h>

PUBLIC int gen_rand_number(int min, int max) {
    int r;
    const int range = 1 + max - min;
    const int buckets = RAND_MAX / range;
    const int limit = buckets * range;  

    do {
        r = rand();
    } while (r >= limit);

    return min + (r / buckets);
}
```

So after a lot of Googling, I realized maybe the stdlib wasn't implemented on this OS, however I checked and

it is defined on: include/stdlib.h

and implemented on: src/lib/libc/stdlib/rand.c as follows:

```
int rand(void)
{
    _next = (_next * 1103515245) + 12345;
    return ((_next >> 16) & 0x7fff);
}
```

I realize this is a quite specific problem, but I hope someone is able to help me out. Also, if more information is needed, please let me know.

[If you want to look at the whole OS code](https://github.com/ppenna/nanvix)

Since this is coming up, I'm using a makefile:

export EDUCATIONAL_KERNEL=1

```
# Directories.
export BINDIR   = $(CURDIR)/bin
export SBINDIR  = $(BINDIR)/sbin
export UBINDIR  = $(BINDIR)/ubin
export DOCDIR   = $(CURDIR)/doc
export INCDIR   = $(CURDIR)/include
export LIBDIR   = $(CURDIR)/lib
export DOXYDIR  = $(CURDIR)/doxygen
export SRCDIR   = $(CURDIR)/src
export TOOLSDIR = $(CURDIR)/tools

# Toolchain
export CC = $(TARGET)-gcc
export LD = $(TARGET)-ld
export AR = $(TARGET)-ar

# Random number for chaos.
export KEY = 13

# Toolchain configuration.
export CFLAGS    = -I $(INCDIR)
export CFLAGS   += -DKERNEL_HASH=$(KEY) -DEDUCATIONAL_KERNEL=$(EDUCATIONAL_KERNEL)
export CFLAGS   += -std=c99 -pedantic-errors -fextended-identifiers
export CFLAGS   += -nostdlib -nostdinc -fno-builtin -fno-stack-protector
export CFLAGS   += -Wall -Wextra -Werror
export CFLAGS   += -Wstack-usage=3192 -Wlogical-op
export CFLAGS   += -Wredundant-decls -Wvla
export ASMFLAGS  = -Wa,--divide,--warn
export ARFLAGS   = -vq
export LDFLAGS   = -Wl,-T $(LIBDIR)/link.ld

# Resolves conflicts.
.PHONY: tools

# Builds everything.
all: nanvix documentation

# Builds Nanvix.
nanvix:
    mkdir -p $(BINDIR)
    mkdir -p $(SBINDIR)
    mkdir -p $(UBINDIR)
    cd $(SRCDIR) && $(MAKE) all

# Builds system's image.
image: $(BINDIR)/kernel tools
    mkdir -p $(BINDIR)
    bash $(TOOLSDIR)/build/build-img.sh $(EDUCATIONAL_KERNEL)

# Builds documentation.
documentation:
    doxygen $(DOXYDIR)/kernel.config

# Builds tools.
tools:
    mkdir -p $(BINDIR)
    cd $(TOOLSDIR) && $(MAKE) all

# Cleans compilation files.
clean:
    @rm -f *.img
    @rm -rf $(BINDIR)
    @rm -rf $(DOCDIR)/*-kernel
    cd $(SRCDIR) && $(MAKE) clean
    cd $(TOOLSDIR) && $(MAKE) clean
```

Comment: What command did you use when you got that error message?

Comment: posted the makefile @DavidSchwartz

Comment: you should add a big fat red blinking warning light at the top of your post, that you're not working in a normal C environment but instead in an embedded environment.

Comment: Sorry @BodoThiesen, it is the first sentence of the post but I'll make it red

Comment: no prob, I just didn't realize it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since you're building a freestanding OS, not an application, you have no access to the standard library. If you look in the makefile, you'll see that it passes `-nostdlib -nostdinc` to the compiler and linker. If your codebase provides a PRNG, you can use it. Otherwise, you'll need to add an implementation of one.

Comment: First of all thanks for the answer. I get what you're saying, but if they implemented stdlib here https://github.com/ppenna/nanvix/tree/master/src/lib/libc/stdlib shouldn't I be able to use it? When I googled around before posting this I reached the same conclusion as you but I figured if they implemented it I could use it. Right?

Comment: @leofontes You should, but on quick inspection, it seems to be broken. Have a look in `rand.h` and you'll see it says there is a definition of `rand` but there isn't. It's not clear what you're doing -- are you trying to build the OS itself or are you trying to build an application for it? If the former, are you sure the OS is allowed to use the library? If the latter, why are you typing `make nanvix`?

Comment: This is an extra bonus assignment, I already implemented the dynamic priorities proposed but now I'm trying to build a lottery scheduler for processes on this OS. I'm not asking for help on the assignment, just want to understand what is going on. I tried declaring the rand function on the .h file but it still doesn't work, I'll try to fix the library.. Thank you for your help David. :)

Comment: writing a function prototype like "int rand(void);" in a header file and including that only promises the compiler "somewhere there is a function by that name". If the function is missing, the linker will slap you with the error message you quoted above.

Comment: Yeah so I know this isn't the most elegant solution but I rewrote it from the rand.c file inside my sched.h, it passed the proposed tests but I'll try to sit down with the TA that wrote the OS because I'm pretty sure he made a mistake haha, I'll keep you guys posted just for curiosity sake but thank you very much, gave me a good understanding of the situation.

Comment: It may simply be that you are writing part of the OS which is not allowed to use the standard library because that's for applications written for the OS, not for the OS itself. But I'm not sure.

Answer (score 1):

You need to link in your own implementation of the c library somewhat like this:

```
$ gcc -LPATH -lc $object_files -o executable
```

where PATH is the relative path to your own libc

Or ... probably you should better listen to David Schwartz, who already pointed out, that you have to implement rand yourself. Here it means: You need to implement it in the kernel, because I guess, sched.c is a file belonging to your kernel, and so, the stdclib functions are not available to you.

Comment: Im using a makefile, how can I add that? Sorry I'm still learning C

Comment: forget my answer.

Comment: Check what I commented on David's answer please @BodoThiesen

Comment: yea, I read it. you got a kernel. and you got a libstdc. But inside your kernel, your libstdc code is not reachable, right? This is not "your" codebase, you're only hacking on it, right? Yea, you'er not Pedro. So, you have to copy&past the rand function from libstdc to kernel.

Comment: Yes, it was given to us to hack and implement some features on the scheduler. I guess I'll try to fix this library as well, thank you for the help.

Comment: it's not about "fixing" the library, the exercise here is to understand, that user land code is not reachable from kernel space.